# How to convert the Canvas ImageData object to string?

Tags: html, canvas

I am not sure is this possible to be done. I need to hold the ImageData Object return by getImageData() from a Canvas for later use, but I have no idea on how to do that. Is there a way to convert ImageData object to string like what toDataURL does?

Comment: Can you define "later use"

Comment: @Kaiido The platform I am using is called Confirmit which is an online survey development platform. The feature of an online survey is asking questions page by page. I have a project now which we need to have a  canvas to allow users draw their responses on every page. The problem is if we don't store the canvas data somewhere, the responses they gave will lost by the time they go back to the same page. I know I can store the canvas to Image then load the image back to canvas, but that will be pretty slow and apparently we don't want to slow down the loading speed for online respondents.

Comment: And where would you store this string then? On server? The file size would be greater than if saved as a compressed image file (jpeg and png both compress the data). On user's machine like localStorage? Then loading this big data + putting it on the context would be done synchronously which might produce an UI freeze, worse than simple async latency in most cases. Stick with simplicity, it always pays. (if you want to avoid storing server side, you can save small images as dataURI in localStorage, though I won't recommend it, or as binary (Blob) in IndexedDB).

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your suggestion. The flow for Confirmit is a bit different.  Data will be saved automatically in the fields (input, textarea, select, eg) created by them (those fields will be created by the time we insert Single or Multi Choice questions into the survey). Confirmit also allow developer to create their own html object (maybe in question text or instructions), but the data input to those fields will lost when we go to next page if we don't find a way to save it. What I am trying to do is save the Canvas data as a string in system generated <input> fields

Comment: @Kaiido So the string will be saved (I think there is a database behind). By the time we go back to this page, we use that saved string to populate the Canvas.

Comment: Then save as dataURL, as I said, it will be smaller than the raw imageData, and the will be parsed+drawn asynchronously, which will avoid page freezes.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will have more try.